# Order By Syntax Error

Tags: t-sql

Can't figure out why I get the error: ncorrect syntax near 'desc'.
it's saying the last line is the issue or around there...

```
select  e.DealID,    
    e.TestID, 
    e.Quantity,
    case     
        Description  
            when 'Active' then 'Positive' else e.Description      
    end as Description,   
    (SUM(e.Price * e.SalePrice) / NULLIF(SUM(e.SalePrice), 0)) as Price
from Product e
WHERE ArchiveID = @ArchiveID 
group by    e.TestID,
        Description,
        e.Quantity
order by    e.TestID,
        Description
```

Comment: I failed on this post.  I do not have a comma after my aggregate...sorry.  Updating the original post AGAIN, same issue though as my original issue still remains.

Comment: so that's what the real post should be...it's accurate now.  When I remove the aggregate, it works but why?  I need that aggregate returned though.

Comment: I have a feeling I'm gonna get a lot of down votes :)

Comment: again if I take out the aggregate, my query works...

Comment: Delete while you can! ;p

Answer (score 1):

desc is a reserved word.

the group by is confused, and the case statement probably as well.

Comment: that's just for this post, it's not actually called that in my real query

Comment: well then you need a real column name before the word desc. - show your real query for real help :)

Comment: after your edit, the column Description does not exist.  you could change that to the number 4 to indicate the 4th column to avoid naming issues

Answer (score 0):

Extra comma:

```
order by    e.TestID,
                    ^---here
        Desc
```

which turns `desc` not into "descending", but a field named `desc`, which'll be a syntax error and invalid field name.

Comment: check out the new name for description, its unique, not a reserve word anymore which is more like my real query

Comment: bad post by me, there IS a comma there.  Feel free to smack me now.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Replaced while chasing OP's code.

```
select  e.DealID,     
    e.TestID,  
    e.Quantity, 
    case      
        Description   
            when 'Active' then 'Positive' else e.Description       
    end as Description,    
    (SUM(e.Price * e.SalePrice) / NULLIF(SUM(e.SalePrice), 0)) as Price 
from Product e 
WHERE ArchiveID = @ArchiveID  
group by    e.TestID, -- Added comma.
        Description, 
        e.Quantity 
order by    e.TestID, 
        Description
```

Comment: why does that matter?  I need that weighted average to be returned!

Comment: Look a the updated code in my orignal post...I have a non reserve word for description, bad post by me.

Comment: sorry I posted badly, see my updated post.  My real query doesn't have a comma after the aggregate...sorry for the wasted time here.  Problem still remains.

Comment: Ok so why does it matter if the aggregates are there, I removed the aggregates and yes it works but again I need those aggregates returned

Comment: Does the additional comma in the `group by` clause help?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  If so, which version?

Answer (score 0):

stupid, I had commented out the END in my proc.  that was the entire problem.